# Unable to update redux state and realm database

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, realm

I'm trying to update my redux store with data that was entered in my `useState`.
While I was researching this error logs, I've noticed that in most cases it is related to realm database, somehow it seems to affect my redux store even if I'm not trying to up my database.

```
 LOG  [Error: Wrong transactional state (no active transaction, wrong type of transaction, or transaction already in progress)
Exception backtrace:
<backtrace not supported on this platform>]
 ERROR  Error: Wrong transactional state (no active transaction, wrong type of transaction, or transaction already in progress)
Exception backtrace:
<backtrace not supported on this platform>
```

my action ruction is as follows:

```js
    editEntity: (state, {payload}: any) => {
      let entity = state.businesses?.find(x =>
        x.businessId?.equals(payload.businessId),
      );

      if (entity) {
        entity.name = payload.name;
      }
    }
```

as you can see, all I'm updating is my redux state.

On the other hand when I create a new business object and save it to my realm database, I first create the object and check if my state array has any other business entities. If it has previous entities, they will all be set to false e.g `isDefault: false` while the new entity will be set to true automatically. Below is the function I used to create an entity and check whether to set `isDefault` to `false || true`:

```
  const addHandler = async () => {
    try {
      //first create the realm object
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.create(
          'BusinessEntity',
          TBusiness.generate(
            business.accountingPeriodId!,
            business.name!,
            business.registrationNumber!,
            business.vatRegistered!,
            business.vatNumber!,
            business.startDate!,
            business.endDate!,
            business.streetAddress!,
            business.suburb!,
            business.province!,
            business.postalCode!,
            business.autoGenerateCustomerCode!,
            business.autoGenerateItemCode!,
            business.invoiceMessage!,
            business.quotationMessage!,
            business.bankName!,
            business.branchCode!,
            business.accountNumber!,
            business.accountName!,
          ),
        );
      });

      let newBusiness = await query.find(x => x.name === business.name);
      let businessObject = realm.objects(TBusiness);

      dispatch(addBusinessAction(newBusiness));

      //update state, set previous to false
      if (businessArray.businesses!.length > 0) {
        //update any business entity that was created to "false"
        //businessObject.findIndex(x => {
        //
        //if (x.name !== business.name) {
        //x.isDefault = false;
        //}
        //});
        businessObject.forEach(x => {
          if (x.name !== business.name) {
            return (x.isDefault = false);
          }
        });
      }

      setBusiness({});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  };
```

But when I run the function, I get the following logs:

```
 LOG  [Error: Wrong transactional state (no active transaction, wrong type of transaction, or transaction already in progress)
Exception backtrace:
0   Numberz                             0x00000001053aca9f _ZN5realm10LogicErrorC1ENS0_9ErrorKindE + 47
1   Numberz                             0x000000010577f472 _ZN5realm4Node16do_copy_on_writeEm + 354
2   Numberz                             0x00000001056bc497 _ZN5realm5Array3setEmx + 103
3   Numberz                             0x000000010577fadd _ZN5realm3Obj3setIbEERS0_NS_6ColKeyET_b + 637
4   Numberz                             0x00000001053ba358 _ZN5realm6Object23set_property_value_implIPK13OpaqueJSValueNS_2js14NativeAccessorINS_3jsc5TypesEEEEEvRT0_RKNS_8PropertyET_NS_12CreatePolicyEb + 3592
5   Numberz                             0x00000001053d6fa8 _ZN5realm2js16RealmObjectClassINS_3jsc5TypesEE12set_propertyEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueRKNS0_6StringIS3_EEPKS8_ + 504
6   Numberz                             0x0000000105435068 _ZN5realm2js4wrapIXadL_ZNS0_16RealmObjectClassINS_3jsc5TypesEE12set_propertyEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueRKNS0_6StringIS4_EEPKS9_EEEEbS8_SA_P14OpaqueJSStringSG_PSG_ + 56
7   Numberz                             0x000000010543e5e5 _ZN5realm3jsc10ObjectWrapINS_2js16RealmObjectClassINS0_5TypesEEEE15accessor_setterEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueSB_mPKPKSA_PSD_ + 53
8   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff318abd63 _ZN3JSC16JSCallbackObjectINS_16JSNonFinalObjectEE4callEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_9CallFrameE + 627
9   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31836021 vmEntryToNative + 226
10  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31ee2c1d _ZN3JSC11Interpreter11executeCallEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_8JSObjectERKNS_8CallDataENS_7JSValueERKNS_7ArgListE + 573
11  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff321a18f4 _ZN3JSC10callSetterEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectENS_7JSValueES2_S2_NS_8ECMAModeE + 308
12  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff32249625 _ZN3JSC8JSObject13putInlineSlowEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectENS_12PropertyNameENS_7JSValueERNS_15PutPropertySlotE + 1077
13  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31fd9fb4 llint_slow_path_put_by_id + 1252
14  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3183f8cd llint_entry + 38921
15  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
16  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
17  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
18  ???                                 0x0000507ac899f7ae 0x0 + 88488281765806
19  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
20  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
21  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
22  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
23  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
24  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
25  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
26  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
27  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
28  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
29  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
30  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
31  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff318509b1 llint_entry + 108781
32  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
33  ???                                 0x0000507ac8ab4ac3 0x0 + 88488282901187
34  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
35  ???                                 0x0000507ac8ab524f 0x0 + 88488282903119
36  ???                                 0x0000507ac8a9fa5b 0x0 + 88488282815067
37  ???                                 0x0000507ac86f2feb 0x0 + 88488278962155
38  ???                                 0x0000507ac8a9f0e9 0x0 + 88488282812649
39  ???                                 0x0000507ac86025d7 0x0 + 88488277976535
40  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31835ecf vmEntryToJavaScript + 216
41  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31ee2be6 _ZN3JSC11Interpreter11executeCallEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_8JSObjectERKNS_8CallDataENS_7JSValueERKNS_7ArgListE + 518
42  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff321e66b7 _ZN3JSC27boundThisNoArgsFunctionCallEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_9CallFrameE + 743
43  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31836021 vmEntryToNative + 226
44  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31ee2c1d _ZN3JSC11Interpreter11executeCallEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_8JSObjectERKNS_8CallDataENS_7JSValueERKNS_7ArgListE + 573
45  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff32135714 _ZN3JSC12profiledCallEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectENS_15ProfilingReasonENS_7JSValueERKNS_8CallDataES3_RKNS_7ArgListE + 164
46  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff318b9706 JSObjectCallAsFunction + 694
47  Numberz                             0x00000001052ae838 _ZN8facebook3jsc10JSCRuntime4callERKNS_3jsi8FunctionERKNS2_5ValueEPS7_m + 344
48  Numberz                             0x00000001052bea5d _ZNK8facebook3jsi8Function4callERNS0_7RuntimeEPKNS0_5ValueEm + 125
49  Numberz                             0x00000001052be97b _ZNK8facebook3jsi8Function4callERNS0_7RuntimeESt16initializer_listINS0_5ValueEE + 107
50  Numberz                             0x00000001052e1890 _ZNK8facebook3jsi8Function4callIJRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEESB_NS0_5ValueEEEESC_RNS0_7RuntimeEDpOT_ + 368
51  Numberz                             0x00000001052e16b6 _ZZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor12callFunctionERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEESA_RKN5folly7dynamicEENK3$_5clEv + 166
52  Numberz                             0x00000001052e15ed _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor12callFunctionERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESB_RKN5folly7dynamicEE3$_5JEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSI_DpOSJ_ + 29
53  Numberz                             0x00000001052e159d _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor12callFunctionERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESD_RKN5folly7dynamicEE3$_5EEEvDpOT_ + 29
54  Numberz                             0x00000001052e156d _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor12callFunctionERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESC_RKN5folly7dynamicEE3$_5NS8_ISH_EEFvvEEclEv + 29
55  Numberz                             0x00000001052e049e _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor12callFunctionERKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESC_RKN5folly7dynamicEE3$_5NS8_ISH_EEFvvEEclEv + 30
56  Numberz                             0x0000000105321f85 _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvvEEclEv + 53
57  Numberz                             0x0000000105321e95 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvvEEclEv + 21
58  Numberz                             0x0000000104ffe2f9 _ZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor21defaultTimeoutInvokerERKNSt3__18functionIFvvEEENS3_IFNS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEE + 25
59  Numberz                             0x0000000105000ccc _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEENS1_IFNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEEEJS5_SD_EEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSH_DpOSI_ + 108
60  Numberz                             0x0000000105000c37 _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEENS3_IFNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEEES7_SF_EEEvDpOT_ + 71
61  Numberz                             0x0000000105000bc7 _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEENS2_IFNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEEENSA_ISG_EESF_EclES6_OSE_ + 71
62  Numberz                             0x0000000104fff7c8 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEENS2_IFNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEEENSA_ISG_EESF_EclES6_OSE_ + 72
63  Numberz                             0x00000001052dfaba _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEENS2_IFNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEEEEclES6_OSE_ + 106
64  Numberz                             0x00000001052cf825 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvRKNS0_IFvvEEENS0_IFNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEvEEEEEclES4_SC_ + 69
65  Numberz                             0x00000001052cf46b _ZN8facebook5react11JSIExecutor12callFunctionERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEESA_RKN5folly7dynamicE + 491
66  Numberz                             0x0000000105295363 _ZZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge12callFunctionEONSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEES9_ON5folly7dynamicEENK3$_2clEPNS0_10JSExecutorE + 739
67  Numberz                             0x0000000105295062 _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge12callFunctionEONS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESA_ON5folly7dynamicEE3$_2JPNS2_10JSExecutorEEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSI_DpOSJ_ + 50
68  Numberz                             0x0000000105295002 _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge12callFunctionEONS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESC_ON5folly7dynamicEE3$_2PNS4_10JSExecutorEEEEvDpOT_ + 50
69  Numberz                             0x0000000105294fc2 _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge12callFunctionEONS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ON5folly7dynamicEE3$_2NS8_ISF_EEFvPNS3_10JSExecutorEEEclEOSI_ + 50
70  Numberz                             0x0000000105293c43 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge12callFunctionEONS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEESB_ON5folly7dynamicEE3$_2NS8_ISF_EEFvPNS3_10JSExecutorEEEclEOSI_ + 51
71  Numberz                             0x00000001052a05dd _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvPN8facebook5react10JSExecutorEEEclEOS5_ + 77
72  Numberz                             0x00000001052a0560 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvPN8facebook5react10JSExecutorEEEclES4_ + 48
73  Numberz                             0x00000001052a0528 _ZZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge18runOnExecutorQueueENSt3__18functionIFvPNS0_10JSExecutorEEEEENK3$_8clEv + 104
74  Numberz                             0x00000001052a049d _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge18runOnExecutorQueueENS_8functionIFvPNS2_10JSExecutorEEEEE3$_8JEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSB_DpOSC_ + 29
75  Numberz                             0x00000001052a044d _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge18runOnExecutorQueueENS_8functionIFvPNS4_10JSExecutorEEEEE3$_8EEEvDpOT_ + 29
76  Numberz                             0x00000001052a041d _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge18runOnExecutorQueueENS_8functionIFvPNS3_10JSExecutorEEEEE3$_8NS_9allocatorISA_EEFvvEEclEv + 29
77  Numberz                             0x000000010529ef7e _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge18runOnExecutorQueueENS_8functionIFvPNS3_10JSExecutorEEEEE3$_8NS_9allocatorISA_EEFvvEEclEv + 30
78  Numberz                             0x0000000105321f85 _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvvEEclEv + 53
79  Numberz                             0x0000000105321e95 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvvEEclEv + 21
80  Numberz                             0x0000000105060cd5 _ZN8facebook5react17tryAndReturnErrorERKNSt3__18functionIFvvEEE + 21
81  Numberz                             0x00000001050928b1 _ZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread7tryFuncERKNSt3__18functionIFvvEEE + 33
82  Numberz                             0x00000001050981ce _ZZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread10runOnQueueEONSt3__18functionIFvvEEEENK3$_1clEv + 94
83  Numberz                             0x000000010509814d _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread10runOnQueueEONS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$_1JEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSA_DpOSB_ + 29
84  Numberz                             0x00000001050980fd _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread10runOnQueueEONS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$_1EEEvDpOT_ + 29
85  Numberz                             0x00000001050980cd _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread10runOnQueueEONS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$_1NS_9allocatorIS9_EES6_EclEv + 29
86  Numberz                             0x0000000105096d3e _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread10runOnQueueEONS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$_1NS_9allocatorIS9_EES6_EclEv + 30
87  Numberz                             0x0000000105321f85 _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvvEEclEv + 53
88  Numberz                             0x0000000105321e95 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvvEEclEv + 21
89  Numberz                             0x0000000105092510 ___ZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread8runAsyncENSt3__18functionIFvvEEE_block_invoke + 48
90  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20390120 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
91  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038f534 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 434
92  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20389f44 __CFRunLoopRun + 899
93  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
94  Numberz                             0x000000010502b891 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 993
95  Foundation                          0x00007fff20858e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1042
96  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff61167109 _pthread_start + 148
97  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff61162b8b thread_start + 15]
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
Error: Wrong transactional state (no active transaction, wrong type of transaction, or transaction already in progress)
Exception backtrace:
0   Numberz                             0x00000001053aca9f _ZN5realm10LogicErrorC1ENS0_9ErrorKindE + 47
1   Numberz                             0x000000010577f472 _ZN5realm4Node16do_copy_on_writeEm + 354
2   Numberz                             0x00000001056bc497 _ZN5realm5Array3setEmx + 103
3   Numberz                             0x000000010577fadd _ZN5realm3Obj3setIbEERS0_NS_6ColKeyET_b + 637
4   Numberz                             0x00000001053ba358 _ZN5realm6Object23set_property_value_implIPK13OpaqueJSValueNS_2js14NativeAccessorINS_3jsc5TypesEEEEEvRT0_RKNS_8PropertyET_NS_12CreatePolicyEb + 3592
5   Numberz                             0x00000001053d6fa8 _ZN5realm2js16RealmObjectClassINS_3jsc5TypesEE12set_propertyEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueRKNS0_6StringIS3_EEPKS8_ + 504
6   Numberz                             0x0000000105435068 _ZN5realm2js4wrapIXadL_ZNS0_16RealmObjectClassINS_3jsc5TypesEE12set_propertyEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueRKNS0_6StringIS4_EEPKS9_EEEEbS8_SA_P14OpaqueJSStringSG_PSG_ + 56
7   Numberz                             0x000000010543e5e5 _ZN5realm3jsc10ObjectWrapINS_2js16RealmObjectClassINS0_5TypesEEEE15accessor_setterEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueSB_mPKPKSA_PSD_ + 53
8   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff318abd63 _ZN3JSC16JSCallbackObjectINS_16JSNonFinalObjectEE4callEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_9CallFrameE + 627
9   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31836021 vmEntryToNative + 226
10  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31ee2c1d _ZN3JSC11Interpreter11executeCallEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_8JSObjectERKNS_8CallDataENS_7JSValueERKNS_7ArgListE + 573
11  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff321a18f4 _ZN3JSC10callSetterEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectENS_7JSValueES2_S2_NS_8ECMAModeE + 308
12  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff32249625 _ZN3JSC8JSObject13putInlineSlowEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectENS_12PropertyNameENS_7JSValueERNS_15PutPropertySlotE + 1077
13  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31fd9fb4 llint_slow_path_put_by_id + 1252
14  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3183f8cd llint_entry + 38921
15  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
16  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
17  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
18  ???                                 0x0000507ac899f7ae 0x0 + 88488281765806
19  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
20  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
21  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
22  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
23  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
24  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
25  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
26  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
27  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
28  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
29  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
30  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
31  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff318509b1 llint_entry + 108781
32  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f949 llint_entry + 104581
33  ???                                 0x0000507ac8ab4ac3 0x0 + 88488282901187
34  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff3184f8c9 llint_entry + 104453
35  ???                                 0x0000507ac8ab524f 0x0 + 88488282903119
36  ???                                 0x0000507ac8a9fa5b 0x0 + 88488282815067
37  ???                                 0x0000507ac86f2feb 0x0 + 88488278962155
38  ???                                 0x0000507ac8a9f0e9 0x0 + 88488282812649
39  ???                                 0x0000507ac86025d7 0x0 + 88488277976535
40  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31835ecf vmEntryToJavaScript + 216
41  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff31ee2be6
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been some time, but I dealed with the exact same issue and found a solution for my situation. I'll share it if it might help someone in the future:

I also got this error `Error: Wrong transactional state` every time I tries to update my Redux store, even though *it had nothing to do with Realm*.

This was solved by changing my Redux action file to use **DEEP COPY** of the existing object in store, instead of shallow copy.

I changed from this (**NOT WORKING**):

```
export const updateUserInfo = (key, value, userDetails) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        if (userDetails == null) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[key] = value;
        } else {
            var obj = userDetails;
            obj[key] = value;
        }
        dispatch({ type: types.USER_DETAILS, flag: obj });
    }
}
```

to this (**WORKING**):

```
function cloneObject(sourceObject) {
    cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sourceObject));
    return cloned;
}

export const updateUserInfo = (key, value, userDetails) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        if (userDetails == null) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[key] = value;
        } else {
            var obj = cloneObject(userDetails);  // <- THIS IS THE MAGIC
            obj[key] = value;
        }
        dispatch({ type: types.USER_DETAILS, flag: obj });
    }
}
```